# Remove certain value from matrix

Tags: python

I want to remove all zeros from a matrix, so each row or column containing zero will be removed.
Like this:
the input is this matrix:

```
np.array([
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [6, 0, 8 ,9,10],
    [11,12,13,14,15],
    [16, 0, 0,19,20]])
```

The three zeros should cause rows 1 & 3 (zero-based indexing) and columns 1 & 2 to get deleted.  The output matrix shall be:

```
np.array([
    [ 1, 4, 5],
    [11,14,15]])
```

So far I´ve tried this:

```
for i in range(0,len(Matrix)):
    Matrix[Matrix[:,i]!=0]
for i in range(len(Matrix),0):
    Matrix[Matrix[i,:]!=0]
```

Comment: Why are you dropping 3 and 6 from your result?  Your output seems confusing.

Comment: How is it that the first row of your matrix has 6 elements, while the others have 5?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish: The objective is to remove every row & column with a 0.  The 2 & 3 columns have zeros.

Comment: Sorry about that - I´m gonna change it right away

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.ix_` to handle the indexing magic:

```
In [26]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,0,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,0,0,19,20]])

In [27]: mask = arr != 0

In [28]: arr[np.ix_(mask.all(1), mask.all(0))]
Out[28]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
       [11, 14, 15]])
```

---

The indexing magic in question is that `np.ix_` will turn the boolean arrays into the right indices for each axis:

```
In [29]: mask.all(1)
Out[29]: array([ True, False,  True, False])

In [30]: mask.all(0)
Out[30]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])

In [31]: np.ix_(mask.all(1), mask.all(0))
Out[31]: 
(array([[0],
        [2]]), array([[0, 3, 4]]))
```

which really isn't so magical at all, it's effectively

```
In [34]: np.arange(len(mask.all(1)))[mask.all(1)]
Out[34]: array([0, 2])
```

behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your initial approach is that the first loop removes all rows with zeros.  When you get to the second loop, there are no zeros remaining, and no clues about where they were, so you can't remove any columns.

in that first loop, instead of removing the row, set all non-zero entries to `NaN` or some other "marker" value.  Then remove every columns with a zero.  Finally, come back and remove the rows with `NaN`.